# Четвертная доля [не о музыке] — грамотно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

*Он владел **четвертной долей** в элитном бильярдном зале и комплексе развлечений в Лите.*
[**Иэн Рэнкин. Чёрная книга**](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=27052&p=82)

Я знаю, что "четвертная доля" — это музыкальный термин.
А правильно ли употреблять такое словосочетание по отношению к имуществу, к собственности или к чему-нибудь ещё?

Answer (score 1):

Это же художественное произведение, воспроизводится разговорная авторская речь. Такой стилистический приём.  В устной речи возможно такое использование (прилагательное от сущ. четверть). В деловой речи, в документах, например, этого допускать нельзя - только одна четвёртая доля.